# Gutenberg editor add a custom category as wrapper for custom blocks

Tags: categories, customization, editor, block-editor

As we know by the provided API from Gutenberg we can create a custom block as

```
const { registerBlockType } = wp.blocks;

registerBlockType( 'my-namespace/my-block', {

})
```

but how do I create a wrapper(category like layout) around my custom blocks in gutenberg editor?
Let's say I want to have a collector for my custom elements as slider, gallery ...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Digging myself deeper in documentation, I got the following result.

There is a way to group your custom blocks around a given category in Gutenberg, and therefore we have the method [`block_categories_all`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/filters/block-filters/#block_categories_all). So with a filter, you can extend the default categories with custom ones.

Here is my example:

```
add_filter( 'block_categories_all', function( $categories, $post ) {
    return array_merge(
        $categories,
        array(
            array(
                'slug'  => 'my-slug',
                'title' => 'my-title',
            ),
        )
    );
}, 10, 2 );
```

You can find more on this in [the provided API](https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/block-api).

Comment: It looks good but I can't seem to make it work. I can confirm the filter is called in get_block_categories() in post.php as found by Pat J.

Comment: If you are using a plugin you need to update your title line to `'title' => __( 'MyTitle', 'my-plugin-slug' )` make sure your category name for your plugin php and your block js match and don't forget to reactivate your plugin.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to filter the list of default block categories using the `block_categories` filter. Place the code in `functions.php` or `your-plugin.php` file. [Explained here in WordPress Gutenberg Handbook](https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/filters/block-filters/#managing-block-categories)

```
function my_plugin_block_categories( $categories, $post ) {
    if ( $post->post_type !== 'post' ) {
        return $categories;
    }
    return array_merge(
        $categories,
        array(
            array(
                'slug' => 'my-category',
                'title' => __( 'My category', 'my-plugin' ),
                'icon'  => 'wordpress',
            ),
        )
    );
}
add_filter( 'block_categories', 'my_plugin_block_categories', 10, 2 );
```

To use an svg icon you can replace the icon in js. Define your icon.

```
const icon = <svg className='components-panel__icon' width='20' height='20' viewBox='0 0 20 20' aria-hidden='true' role='img' focusable='false' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>
    <rect fill="#ffffff" x="0" y="0" width="20" height="20"/>
    <rect fill="#1163EB" x="2" y="2" width="16" height="16" rx="16"/>
</svg>;
```

and replace the icon using `updateCategory` function from `wp.blocks;` adding class `components-panel__icon` will add a `6px` space to the left side of icon.

```
( function() {
    wp.blocks.updateCategory( 'my-category', { icon: icon } );
} )();
```

Comment: And where should you add the `wp.blocks.updateCategory` function. I have tried this and I cannot get it to work. Can you share a complete working .js file? Also if I register a category and have no blocks assigned to that category should it still be listed? I can't seem to get my category registered either. Also I do not see the block_categories filter in the filter reference docs: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference

Comment: I am not using any boilerplate. here is the entry file for my blocks https://codepen.io/talentedaamer/pen/YMZzjY used in https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-blocks/

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you! Unsetting also works: `updateCategory('ghostkit', { icon: '' })`